# nginx ssl_preread configuration not working reliably

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have nginx compiled with the ssl_preread module.

My configuration is like this

```
stream {
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $mapping {
        sv1.mydomain.com sv1;
        sv2.mydomain.com sv2;
    }

    upstream sv1 {
        10.0.0.10:443;
        # other servers
    }

    upstream sv2 {
        10.0.0.10:8843;
        # other servers
    }

    server {
        listen: 443;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass $mapping;
    }
}
```

DNS for *.mydomain.com all point to my nginx server's external IP. This works fine.

When I go to https://sv1.mydomain.com I get routed to sv1, which is correct.
Then, when I go to https://sv2.mydomain.com I get routed to sv2, which is also correct. **However** when I then navigate back to https://sv1.mydomain.com again, I am routed to sv1 which is wrong!!

It's like something is being cached, but I'm not sure what or where, and not sure how to investigate it.

N.b. this only happens when accessing it externally.

Comment: Did you ever discover a solution for this?

Comment: @Casey No, sorry!